# Is it possible to have custom, default fields added to all new product types In Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have multiple custom fields that will need to be on **all** new product types (Commerce 2). The fields are already created on the 'default' product type. But new product types do not inherit the custom fields.

Is there a way to have custom fields automatically added to all new product types?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing that just works.

You could define them as a base field through code by defining them in hook_entity_base_field_info(), so for example how scheduler module does that. Then they will be non-configurable fields that are always there. If they're not multiple, they will even be added to the product base tables.

Those kind of fields are a bit tricky to uninstall.

The other option is implementing a hook_commerce_product_type_insert() and then copy the configurable fields you want from the default type and add them to that new bundle as well.

Comment: Thanks. I think using hook_commerce_product_type_insert()  will be the route for me to use. That way I can optionally use logic to determine if I want to install the fields on the product. Thanks!